# Is there anything I can do if I get ripped off?

Tags: team-fortress-2, steam

I recently got scammed in a trade in Team Fortress 2. I know the person who did it. Is there any way for me to get my items back? Or will I have to live with the shame of my ignorance forever?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, unless you convince them to "do the right thing," you're stuck.  Valve's [policy on Steam Trading](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9958-MJDG-3003) is very clear on this:

> Steam will not return any items or gifts that you feel have been traded unfairly. There are no exceptions to this policy. All trades are final.   If you were scammed, you may report this scam to Steam Support so that action may be taken against the scammer.

The article goes on to state that making sure you are comfortable with the terms of a trade during the trading process is fully your responsibility.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to make him give it back, but he said he sold it. I checked his inventory and sadly he did.